Error: export 'ɵɵInputFlags' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
I upgraded from angular 14 to 17, and when I tried to run my project. I get this error: Error:
export 'ɵɵInputFlags' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core' 

deleting node modules folder doesn't help
This is my config:
"dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~17.3.3",
        "@angular/cdk": "~17.3.3",
        "@angular/cli": "^17.3.3",
        "@angular/common": "~17.3.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "~17.3.3",
        "@angular/core": "~17.3.3",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^15.0.0-beta.42",
        "@angular/forms": "~17.3.3",
        "@angular/material": "^17.3.3",
        "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "~17.3.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~17.3.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~17.3.3",
        "@angular/router": "~17.3.3",
        "@fontsource/poppins": "^4.5.10",
        "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.8",
        "@ngneat/transloco": "^4.1.1",
        "ace-builds": "^1.4.14",
        "chart.js": "^3.8.0",
        "chartist": "^0.11.4",
        "chartjs-adapter-moment": "^1.0.0",
        "core-js": "^3.27.1",
        "git": "^0.1.5",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
        "material-icons": "^1.13.3",
        "micromark": "^3.0.10",
        "moment": "^2.29.3",
        "monaco-editor": "^0.40.0",
        "ng-chartist": "^8.2.0",
        "ng2-charts": "^3.0.11",
        "ngx-cookie-service": "^17.1.0",
        "ngx-monaco-editor": "^12.0.0",
        "rxjs": "^7.5.5",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
        "sass": "^1.50.1",
        "tslib": "^2.3.1",
        "zone.js": "^0.14.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~17.3.3",
        "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~17.3.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~17.3.3",
        "@types/chartist": "^0.9.48",
        "@types/jasmine": "^4.0.3",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
        "@types/node": "^17.0.45",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
        "concurrently": "^7.6.0",
        "cypress": "^10.11.0",
        "husky": "^8.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "^4.1.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
        "karma": "^6.3.19",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
        "karma-jasmine": "^5.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
        "open-cli": "^7.2.0",
        "prettier": "3.1.1",
        "protractor": "^7.0.0",
        "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
        "tslint": "^6.1.3",
        "typescript": "5.4.4"
    }


The error should show a filepath preceding this string, which indicates which package is causing the error. Most likely it's a package with dependencies that don't (yet) support Angular 17.

I had this error message when I updated then downgraded my angular webapp, the compiler option in tsconfig.json were changed and caused a similar error message.
Specifically, these lines :
"compilerOptions": {
   ...
  "target": "es2017",
  "module": "es2020"
}

